# Laravel mail authentication method

Tags: php, laravel, email, authentication, smtp

I'm trying to add one from authentication method (PLAIN, LOGIN, CRAM-MD5) to SMTP in Laravel, but I don't seeing that *config/mail.php* use authentication.

Any ideas where should I put authentication method?

Comment: It depends on mail engine and client.

Comment: Isn't the authentication in your `.env` file?

Comment: Actually I haven't authentication in SMTP and I'd like to add. So I put authentication variable in my .env file and I think where should I add more.